# How to: pass data from controller to JavaScript in Laravel 4?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-4

I'm developing a mobile web app with Laravel 4 and jQuery Mobile and I have some problems to pass data from Controller to JavaScript file. I find a solution but I think there is a proper way to do that.

Here is my code:

**MapController.php**

```
class MapController extends BaseController 
{
    public function showMap($id)
    {
        $club = Club::find($id);
        return View::make('pages.map', array('club' => $club));
    }
}
```

**pages/map.php**

```
<div id="picture" data-role="dialog">
  <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
    <h1>
      Upload picture
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    code here...
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var id_club = '<?php echo $club->id ?>';
  </script>
  <script src="public/js/map.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</div>
```

Does anyone know if there is a better solution to pass data from controller to JavaScript?

Comment: Better way is to request it by AJAX via JSON. Or add hidden input and get it from there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="club-id" value="<?php echo $club->id ?>" />
```

### Javascript

```
var club_id = $('#club-id').val().trim();
```

Answer (score 11):

Use this package https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer

```
public function index()
{
    JavaScript::put([
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'user' => User::first(),
        'age' => 29
    ]);

    return View::make('hello');
}
```

Comment: Can we send an object or an array with it ?

Comment: Yes we can send anything to the view from a controller using this package.